# partitions of k parts, with parts from m to n elements

Tags: python, set, combinatorics

more-itertools has set_partitions to yield the set partitions of a set into k parts, as shown here: https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.set_partitions

but I need partitions with parts from m to n elements, without calculating all partitions. For example,

the partitions of abcd are

```
['a', 'bcd']
['ab', 'cd']*
['b', 'acd']
['abc', 'd']
['bc', 'ad']*
['ac', 'bd']*
['c', 'abd']
```

but only the partitions with * have parts from 2 to 3 elements (vg. 'ab' has 2 elements).

obtain the partitions of k parts, with parts from m to n elements.

for example: We are given a set with 9 elements, and we want to find all possible partitions of this set into 4 parts. Each part must contain more than 1 element and less than 4.

set = 'abcdefghi'

two examples of partition with 4 parts, each one with more than 1 element and less than 4:

'abc','de','fg','hi'

'ad','bc','efg','hi'

I would to find all partitions of this sort.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your example of partitioning of 'abcd' in 2-3 size parts includes some permutations (but not all, then on what basis?).  Assuming that you are only looking for partitions, a recursive generator function can produce the desired result:

```
def part(A,k,m,n):
    if len(A)<k*m: return
    if k==1:
        if len(A)<=n: yield [A]
        return
    for p in range(m,n+1):
        for rest in part(A[p:],k-1,m,n):
            yield [A[:p],*rest]
```

output:

```
for p in part('abcd',2,2,3):
    print(p)

['ab', 'cd'] 


for p in part('abcdefghi',4,1,3):
    print(p)

['a', 'bc', 'def', 'ghi']
['a', 'bcd', 'ef', 'ghi']
['a', 'bcd', 'efg', 'hi']
['ab', 'c', 'def', 'ghi']
['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'ghi']
['ab', 'cd', 'efg', 'hi']
['ab', 'cde', 'f', 'ghi']
['ab', 'cde', 'fg', 'hi']
['ab', 'cde', 'fgh', 'i']
['abc', 'd', 'ef', 'ghi']
['abc', 'd', 'efg', 'hi']
['abc', 'de', 'f', 'ghi']
['abc', 'de', 'fg', 'hi']
['abc', 'de', 'fgh', 'i']
['abc', 'def', 'g', 'hi']
['abc', 'def', 'gh', 'i']
```

If you actually need partitions of all permutations, this function can be used in combination with itertools permutations function:

```
from itertools import permutations
def permpart(A,k,m,n):
    for pA in permutations(A):
        yield from part(pA,k,m,n)
```

output:

```
for p in permpart('abcd',2,2,3):
    print(*map(''.join,p))

ab cd
ab dc
ac bd
ac db
ad bc
ad cb
ba cd
ba dc
bc ad
bc da
bd ac
bd ca
ca bd
ca db
cb ad
cb da
cd ab
cd ba
da bc
da cb
db ac
db ca
dc ab
dc ba
```